# How to add request header to HttpClient request?

Tags: android, http-headers

I need to add non standard request header that has format like this:(X-MMP-Params: fs=640x0).
I'm using HTTPClient here is the code:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
String getURL = "http://example.com";
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
get.setHeader("X-MMP-Params","fs=640x0"); // I set my request header right here
HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);
```

Is this the right way to do that ?

Comment: Does it work? To test, you can set the `User-Agent` header, and download a page that shows a server-retrieved user agent (or make your own PHP page). If the shown user agent is what you set it to be, then this method works.

Comment: For those who wander upon this and think, "Well, was it the right way?!", the answer is yes. This works just fine.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that you [shouldn't use `HttpClient` anymore](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client); at least not for Android projects.

Answer (score -1):

The get request is made with HttpGet:

```
public static InputStream getInputStreamFromUrl(String url) {
  InputStream content = null;
  try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
    content = response.getEntity().getContent();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.("[GET REQUEST]", "Network exception", e);
  }
    return content;
}
```

The POST request is made with 
HttpPost:

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

I personally reccoment to try Retrofit
in following way

```
public interface YourUsersApi {

   //You can use rx.java for sophisticated composition of requests 
   @GET("/users/{user}")
   public Observable<SomeUserModel> fetchUser(@Path("user") String user);

   //or you can just get your model if you use json api
   @GET("/users/{user}")
   public SomeUserModel fetchUser(@Path("user") String user);

   //or if there are some special cases you can process your response manually 
   @GET("/users/{user}")
   public Response fetchUser(@Path("user") String user);

}
```